# question about include instruction in makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm recently reading *Microsoft RPC Programming*, here I have a question about the makefile in chapter 1, here is the portion of the makefile:

```
# FILE NAME: Makefile
# Makefile for the arithmetic application
##
definitions for this makefile
#
APPL=arith
NTRPCLIBS=rpcrt4 . lib rpcns4.1ib libcmt.lib keme!32.1ib
# Include Windows NT macros
#
!include <ntwin32.mak>
```

what I can't understand is the last line, why there is a `!`? I've check the `ntwin32.mak`, here is its content:

```
!include <win32.mak>
```

Then what's the meaning of this, why `!include <win32.mak>`? Why not just `include <win32.mak>`?

Comment: Probably some non-standard Make that Microsoft invented just to be different. :-(

Comment: @Toby Speight Hmmm...OK then

Comment: `Why not just include <win32.mak>?` BTW. Those '<>' are also non-standard in make.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what I can't understand is the last line, why there is a `!`? [...] why `!include <win32.mak>`? Why not just `include <win32.mak>`?

Since you found that (pseudo-)makefile in a book about programming for Microsoft platforms, it is presumably intended for [`nmake`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/nmake-reference?view=vs-2019), Microsoft's variation on `make`.  This implementation has a lot in common with traditional Unix-style `make`, but also some significant differences.  Among the latter is a series of "[preprocessing directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/makefile-preprocessing-directives?view=vs-2019)", which are recognized by the fact that they each begin with an exclamation point (`!`).  `!include` is among these.

The preprocessing directives seem to have been modeled more on the C preprocessor than on traditional `make`, which you may also recognize in the support for angle brackets around the name of the file to be `!include`d.  At the same time, `nmake` uses the same symbol as standard `make` to mark comments (`#`), so that is not available to make their directives match C's exactly.  They've chosen the exclamation point as a substitute.

Overall, although Microsoft still distributes and supports `nmake`, it has long focused on Visual Studio instead as the platform for building software for Windows.  You're probably better off developing expertise with that tool than learning the peculiarities of `nmake`.